# Ubuntu Toshiba Dynadock u3.0

Tags: sound, video, display, displaylink

I am having a few issues with my new [Dynadock u3.0](http://us.toshiba.com/computers/accessories/dynadock/).

First of all, all of the USB connections are working as well as the usb ethernet. The only two issues I am having are with the usb audio and the usb displays. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on System 76's newest Lemur Ultra. I will try to provide as much information as possible.

Right now I have connected to my dock: a Razer mouse, Logitech keyboard, Oyen external hard drive. My displays are a Panasonic, Samsung and HannsG(plugged in directly to laptop via HDMI) and my speakers are an Insignia.

```
dillon@lemur / $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2109:0811  
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 5986:0401 Acer, Inc 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2109:0811  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 2109:0811  
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 17e9:4305 DisplayLink 
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 2109:0811  
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 1532:001c Razer USA, Ltd RZ01-0036 Optical Gaming Mouse [Abyssus]
```

```
dillon@lemur / $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e10000 irq 46
 1 [U30            ]: USB-Audio - dynadock U3.0
                  DisplayLink dynadock U3.0 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, super speed
```

[image: Recognized Sound Devices]

So for the sound I see that the sound card in the dynadock is recognized by my OS, but the GUI for managing sound doesn't seem to pick it up.

As for the displays I have no idea where to begin, I've been researching, but nothing seems to work. I understand that you need a displaylink driver and that some exist for Linux. I even read that the driver has been added to the Linux kernel itself, but I haven't verified that. Anyways, if there is anymore information that I need to give I will be glad to post here.

Comment: the Chip is likely a : DL-3900

Answer (score 1):

There is a display link driver for linux built into the kernel; however, due to the complexity of the dl3000 series chips in the new displaylink usb 3.0 docking stations, there is still no driver available for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Display Link has released a new Ubuntu driver (for 14.04 LTS).

> This driver will support up to 2 displays connected to DisplayLink devices. More than 2 DisplayLink displays may work, but not supported or tested by DisplayLink. Resolutions up to 4K are supported on the appropriate DisplayLink hardware.
>
> Device families supported are:
>
> - DL-5xxx
> - DL-41xx
> - DL-3xxx

More informations and download on [the Display Link knowledge site](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683482)